# Java not honoring the classpath specification with -cp option when running with a jar

Tags: java, properties, classpath, loading

I am running a program like the following:

```
java -cp /deploy/conf -jar test.jar
```

test.jar has a class that tries to load properties from a file located in /deploy/conf like the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")
```

The thing is I print out the classpath from both the thread's class loader and the system class loader and neither contain the value `/deploy/conf` that I specified with the `-cp` option.

How can I make sure that java program passes along the values that I specify with -cp option to the thread's class loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Tools documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for `java` with the `-jar` option:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Usually this means you need to use a Manifest Class-Path entry. In this case you can't refer to an absolute path with a Class-Path entry, so you must load the file as a file, not as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `FileInputStream` directly instead of the resource loading process, e.g. using something like:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream ("/deploy/conf/config.properties");
```